# Visual Studio 2019 CVT1101 & LNK1123 fatal error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

this is my first time using visual studio after reinstall windows and stuff which happened around a year ago, and whenever i tryto compile, i get this error,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TrainerBasic, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
1>CVTRES : fatal error CVT1101: cannot open 'C:\Users\gamz\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{E3BAB312-249D-4367-A832-80B6F6B34AFB}.tmp' for reading
1>Done building project "BasicProgram.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So, i don't have an antivirus software, my hardware is not full, i tried cleaning the solution.. i don't know what could be the problem... and i really want to get back to visual studio, as any other  online compilers don't have windows.h for example. I ALSO TRIED TO USE THE REPAIR FUNCTION IN VISUAL STUDIO. P.S. I am using visual studio community 2019

Answer (score 1):

Linker Tools Error LNK1123:

> Input files must have the Common Object File Format (COFF) format. If
>   an input file is not COFF, the linker automatically tries to convert
>   32-bit OMF objects to COFF, or runs CVTRES.EXE to convert resource
>   files. This message indicates that the linker could not convert the
>   file. This can also occur when using an incompatible version of
>   CVTRES.EXE from another installation of Visual Studio, the Windows
>   Development Kit, or .NET Framework.

I suggest you could follow the following methods to fix the issue:

1,Try building with incremental linking disabled.`Property->Linker`. Change the value of **Enable Incremental Linking** to No.

2,Try turning off the Embed Manifest option.`Property-> Manifest Tool->Input and Output`. Change the value of **Embed Manifest** to **No**.

3,Verify that the version of CVTRES.EXE found first in your PATH environment variable matches the version of the build tools, or the version of the Platform Toolset, used by your project.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1123?view=vs-2019

According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/cvtres-errors-cvt1100-through-cvt4001?view=vs-2019)

> The Visual Studio compilers and build tools can report many kinds of
>   errors and warnings. After an error or warning is found, the build
>   tools may make assumptions about code intent and attempt to continue,
>   so that more issues can be reported at the same time. If the tools
>   make the wrong assumption, later errors or warnings may not apply to
>   your project. When you correct issues in your project, always start
>   with the first error or warning that's reported, and rebuild often.
>   One fix may make many subsequent errors go away.

As far as I'm concerned, after you fix link1123 error, CVTRES errors and warnings may go away.

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.